# Android Hide keyboard for password field

Tags: android, virtual-keyboard

While setting  `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);`  for the password
field, the text we are inputting is visible and will not be masked by
dots which is not desirable for password field.

`InputType.TYPE_NULL |  TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD` will display the
keyboard.

If we try setting the content type again as
`TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD`, the virtual keyboard will start
appearing again.

Also tried out the below method which is also not working.
`InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextPasswordnew.getWindowToken(), 0);`

Setting the `InputType` to `NULL` and setting the `TransformationMethod`
still displays locale hints.

Can you please suggest any other possible means on how we can achieve
hiding the virtual keyboard on a password `EditText` field?

We don't want the user to do it from Settings.

Comment: Do you want soft keyboard to stay hidden all the time? Or just when activity starts until user select your password field?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `android:windowSoftInputMode` tag for `activity` element in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Especially at `stateHidden` and `stateAlwaysHidden` values.

But this setting influence behavior of all activity, not just one specific control.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.
Add in your manifest file this strings despite the fact that they are deprecated.

```
android:editable="false"
android:password="true"
```